# return a base collection made from the union of child's one

Tags: c#, collections

I'm trying to retrieve a collection of parent obj based on the sum of the child's one.
Ex:
3 class

```
Animal,  
Dog:Animal,  
Cat:Animal
```

Let's try to explain with some code:

```
Class something{  
    public List <Dog> DogList{get; set;};  
    public List <Cat> CatList{get; set;};

    Public List <Animal> getAnimals{
        get{ return DogList+CatList; }  
    }  
}
```

`getAnimals` should return the sum of the 2 child list's like

```
Public List <Animal> getAnimals{
    get{
        List<Animal> AnimalList = new List<Animal>();

        foreach (Animal child in DogList)
            AnimalList.add(child);

        foreach(Animal child in CatList)
            AnimalList.add(child);

        return AnimalList;
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Does something not work?

Comment: How does this not work already?

Comment: well i don't want to create another obj to duplicate the values (huge amount of data)

Comment: `DogList.Concat<Animal>(CatList)`

Comment: @VeNoMiS Also, it's unlikely your amount of data is "huge" by any objective measure.

Comment: You do not duplicate any data here, the instances that you have in the lists DogList and CatList will also be in your Animal list. No new copies are created. If you for example change one of your cats in CatList then you will directly see the same change in your Animal list without creating the list all over again.

Comment: You have not really explained what your problem is. Does this not work or are you just looking for a way to do this without duplicate all the data (which it does not)? The LINQ answers below does exactly the same as your code so they do not really solve any problem.

Comment: @user707727 The LINQ answers don't really do the same, because LINQ *avoids* creating new collections implicitly when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
public List<Animal> getAnimals()
{
    return DogList.Concat<Animal>(CatList)
                  .ToList();
}
```

or if you want to return unique cats and unique dogs:

```
public List<Animal> getAnimals()
{
    return DogList.Union<Animal>(CatList)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Comment: `Union()` is a set operation, it removes duplicates by adding every element to a hash set. This is probably undesired and at best a waste of time/memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably mean this method, [`Enumerable.Concat<T>`][1]. It is an extension method on any `IEnumerable<T>`, which `List<T>` is, which allows you to take two collections, and produce a new `IEnumerable<T>` that will "contain" the contents of both original collections.

Note that `Concat` is not a collection that makes a copy of the values, it will be a collection you can only enumerate over (like with `foreach`), and when you do, it will enumerate over the two original collections and produce all the elements.

```
public List<Animal> getAnimals() 
{
    return DogList.OfType<Animal>().Concat(CatList).ToList()
}
```

Comment: There is no such method on `List<T>`. (You mean `Enumerable.Concat<T>()`

Comment: I didn't put *dv*, but `DogList.Concat(CatList)` - still won't compile. Sorry, but you have to specify base generic type, like in my answer, in order to use **concat**

Comment: Which is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` so it should work now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Nope. And the `OfType<>()` call is just completely asinine, as is using `Cast<>()`.

Comment: Yep, tried it in LINQPad now, I had it backwards, works now. First interpret the dog list as a list of animals, then concat another list of animals (concat takes `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, this isn't your answer. Why are you modifying it?

Comment: It was the best answer here, the syntax was wrong but the gist of it was correct, I thought it better to just fix the answer instead of posting another one quite similar. You *are* familiar with how SO works, right?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, the answer was just hilariously broken and referred to an imaginary method.

Comment: `Concat` is very much an existing *extension* method, not imaginary at all. Why do you think so? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I meant the `List<T>.Concat()` nonsense. Or the `DogList<Animal>` construct. There was exactly one **word** that the original got right which is "concat". That's hardly enough to count as a "good answer". And it's still using `OfType<>()` which, while not wrong, is also pointless, and misses the point of *why* `DogList.Concat(CatList)` won't compile. (Which is that type inference for method-level generic parameters is fairly dumb and needs a hint.)